# In docker, can I publish a volume with initial data?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I want to share a file storage between two containers. From the documentation, I've seen that you can create and use volumes like this:

```
docker volume create --name DataVolume1
docker run -ti --rm -v DataVolume1:/datavolume1 ubuntu
```

However, I want containers to be able to access an initial set of shared data. Does docker support publishing of volumes? If not, does this mean I should write the initial data manually, after creating the volume, or is there another solution for publishing the data along with the images?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a named volume (not with a host volume, aka bind mount) docker will initialize an empty named volume to the contents of the image at the location you mount it. So if you have files in your image at /datavolume1, and DataVolume1 is empty, docker will copy those files into the named volume.

Comment: Is there any portion of the documentation that explains that in detail? What part of docker is responsible for this? The daemon or the volume driver? Why the difference between bind mounts and named volumes?

Comment: This behavior is explained in the *Populate a volume using a container* section of the documentation https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container

Comment: For a technology designed to simplify and universalize software deployment, this is a surprisingly convoluted solution to seeding a volume with data. It bears semblance to the 'data only container' pattern which is now discouraged. To me, docker volumes scream of a rushed response to a significant gap recently discovered by the masses trying to use redundant (e.g. swarm) database containers while sharing a single data source.